# Are where any features when working with %r8,%r9 etc registers?

Tags: assembly, att

I want to rewrite code of this C function in the Assembly:

```
int digits_amount = digits_num / DIGITS_PER_ITERATION + 1;
const long unsigned int array_length = DIGITS_PER_ITERATION*10*(digits_amount) / 3;
long unsigned int remainders[array_length];  
long unsigned int answ[digits_amount];
int i = 0; 
for (; i < array_length; i++)
    remainders[i] = ARRINIT;
for (i = 0; i < digits_amount; i++) {
    int j = array_length-1;
    long unsigned int quotient = 0;
    long unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (; j >= 0; j--) {
        remainders[j] *= SCALE;
        sum = remainders[j]+quotient*(j+1);
        quotient = sum / (2*j+1);
        remainders[j] = sum - quotient*(2*j+1);
    }
    quotient = sum / SCALE;
    remainders[0] = sum - quotient*SCALE;
    answ[i] = quotient;
} //end of algo, then output
```

Where SCALE = 1000000000, DIGITS_PER_ITERATION = 9, ARRINIT = 200000000, OUTPUT_FORMAT = "%.9lu".
So i tried to do this by the inline assembly:

```
    asm (
    ".L1:\n\t"
        "movq $200000000, (%%rax, %%rcx, 8)\n\t"
        "incq %%rcx\n\t"
    "cmpq %%rdx, %%rcx\n\t"
    "jb .L1\n\t"
    "xorq %%rcx, %%rcx\n\t"
    ".L2:\n\t"
        "pushq %%rbx\n\t"/*for free usage of rbx register*/
        "movq %%rdx, %%r8\n\t"/*j*/
        "decq %%r8\n\t"
        "movq $0, %%r9\n\t"/*quotient*/
        "movq $0, %%r10\n\t"/*sum*/
        ".L3:\n\t" /*inner cycle*/
            "movq (%%rax, %%r8, 8), %%r11\n\t"/*remainders[j]*/
            "pushq %%rax\n\t"
            "movq $1000000000, %%rax\n\t"
            "mulq %%r11\n\t"/*remainders[j]*SCALE*/
            "movq %%rax, %%r11\n\t"
            "movq %%r8, %%rax\n\t"
            "incq %%rax\n\t"
            "mulq %%r9\n\t" /*quotient*(j+1)*/
            "addq %%rax, %%r10\n\t"
            "addq %%r11, %%r10\n\t" /*sum = remainders[j]+quotient*(j+1)*/
            "movq %%r10, %%rax\n\t"
            "movq %%r8, %%rbx\n\t"
            "addq %%rbx, %%rbx\n\t"
            "incq %%rbx\n\t"
            "pushq %%rdx\n\t"
            "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx\n\t"
            "divq %%rbx\n\t" /*sum / (2*j+1)
            "movq %%rax, %%r9\n\t" /*quotient*/
            "movq %%rdx, %%rbx\n\t"/*remainder now in %rbx*/
            "popq %%rdx\n\t"
            "popq %%rax\n\t"
            "movq %%rbx, (%%rax, %%r8, 8)\n\t" /*remainders[j] = remainder*/
            "decq %%r8\n\t"
        "cmpq $0, %%r8\n\t"
        "jge .L3\n\t"
    "movq $1000000000, %%rbx\n\t"
    "pushq %%rdx\n\t"
    "pushq %%rax\n\t"
    "movq %%r10, %%rax\n\t"
    "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx\n\t"
    "divq %%rbx\n\t"
    "movq %%rax, %%r9\n\t"
    "popq %%rax\n\t"
    "movq %%rdx, (%%rax)\n\t"
    "popq %%rdx\n\t"
    "popq %%rbx\n\t"/*get the address of answ array*/
    "movq %%r12, (%%rbx, %%rcx, 8)\n\t"  /*answ[i] = */ 
    "incq %%rcx\n\t" 
    "cmpq %%rdi, %%rcx\n\t"
    "jb .L2\n\t"
    :"=c"(i)
    :"a"(remainders),"c"(i), "d"(array_length), "D"(digits_amount), "b"(answ)/* inputs */
    :/* clobbered */
);
```

In generated code it looks like this:

```
.L1:
movq $200000000, (%rax, %rcx, 8)
incq %rcx
cmpq %rdx, %rcx
jb .L1
xorq %rcx, %rcx
.L2:
pushq %rbx
movq %rdx, %r8
decq %r8
movq $0, %r9
movq $0, %r10
.L3:
movq 0(%rax, %r8, 8), %r11
pushq %rax
movq $1000000000, %rax
mulq %r11
movq %rax, %r11
movq %r8, %rax
incq %rax
mulq %r9
addq %rax, %r10
addq %r11, %r10
movq %r10, %rax
movq %r8, %rbx
addq %rbx, %rbx
incq %rbx
pushq %rdx
xorq %rdx, %rdx
divq %rbx
movq %rax, %r9
movq %rdx, %rbx
popq %rdx
popq %rax
movq %rbx, 0(%rax, %r8, 8)
decq %r8
cmpq $0, %r8
jge .L3
movq $1000000000, %rbx
pushq %rdx
pushq %rax
movq %r10, %rax
xorq %rdx, %rdx
divq %rbx
movq %rax, %r9
popq %rax
movq %rdx, (%rax)
popq %rdx
popq %rbx
movq %r12, (%rbx, %rcx, 8)
incq %rcx
cmpq %rdi, %rcx
jb .L2
```

So, the answers do not match. I checked values in the inner cycle and mentioned, that the first values match, but not the rest. I think, that the problem can be in mul or div, but I can't find it. Is it possible that div can change not only %rdx and %rax? Is it possible that %r8,%r9,... registers are changing without my knowledge? Maybe i've mistaken somewhere. Is it a good way to use so many registers for this? This must be faster then working with memory, so i tried to do it in this way.

Comment: Which values do match?  Which values don't match?  What are they and what should they be?

Comment: There are no instructions that have implicit operands other than the MUL and DIV instructions that use RAX and RDX implicitly. However you inline assembly statement changes a bunch of registers without telling the compiler which could case any number of problems with any code executed after it. Also, there's nothing in your assembly code that would suggest that it would actually run any faster than the C version.

Comment: In addition to what @RossRidge said, you are also changing the contents of input registers.  This is [expressly forbidden](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands) (see the Warning).  Also, using lots of registers may make this specific code run faster, but at a penalty of slowing down things around it which were already using those registers.

Comment: I've found a mistake (one register could be overflowed). It helped, but the program is not worked. Then, I tried not to change inner registers, as you said, and succeed. Thanks for docs. These are more complete as opposed to those that i read earlier